# Processwire Holder/Page implementation

Tags: processwire

How do you implement a holder/page pattern in Processwire.  The idea is simple. One page type manages the list view, and usually contains very little native content. The primary function of this page is to provide a list of its child pages, providing a brief summary for each one, along with a link to its detail view. A second page type will represent the detail view for any given child page, which will typically have a custom template and content fields that make up its identity. Think of it think like a news listings, image galleries, even a Twitter timeline.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: @SilverstripeNewbie: I'd recommend you ask this question over at the ProcessWire Forums: https://processwire.com/talk/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just create pages under parent page then iterate on children pages. Processwire is slow though, better use Silverstripe it's more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I can give examples for two different methods from a recent site I built with Processwire.

First is **NEWS** section:
I have a page called News and it's template is news-listing. Under News, I have news pages and their template is news-detail. news-listing template only accepts news-detail and news-listing for child pages. I allowed news-listing under news-listing if client needs to create sub listing pages under news.

News-listing template basically gets the news with

```
<?php $news = $page->children('template=news-detail'); ?>
```

Second is **Products** section
Site has different section for purposes. Like WOMENS, MENS, KIDS etc. The products are not shared among those main separation. I have a structure like below

- MAIN SEPARATION

  - Products (products are listed under)
  - Categories (categories are listed under)

On product details page you can select multiple categories. On categories page products are listed like this. And on main separation page I have categories listed. Each of these page type has their own templates.

```
$products = $page->rootParent->find("template=product-detail,category={$page->id}");
```

Hope it helps